# How do I display text on mouse rollover of image

Tags: development

I know almost nothing about SharePoint but have been asked to create a departmental page. I have imported an image into a table and want to have text display to the side of the image when the user mouses over it.

Do I need Designer to do that? How would I do that? Please keep it simple, if possible, or as step-by-step for dummies.

Comment: sharepoint version?

Answer (score 1):

### SharePoint 2010

You could use the standard Html attribute `title="someText"`
To use it, you need to open the SharePoint page in **Edit** mode and then under your **Editing Tools** -> **Format Text** you have the Option: **HTML**

Open it and search for your Image (should look like this `<img src="..." alt="..." />`) just add `title="Your Hover Text"` as an attribtue, hit OK and save the page.

Then, if you mouse over it it should look like this
[image: MouseOver]

If you want a styled tooltip you can allways implement a library, but that would require SharePoint Designer